# Unit test for web service (Service Reference) - xml deserialization

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, c#-4.0, deserialization, rhino-mocks

**In Summary**

I need a way to deserialize an XML string into an object normally returned by a 3rd party webservice.

Using C#.

**In Detail**

I have code that consumes a 3rd party Service Reference (Web Service) - so the usual stuff: we pass in a Request object and it returns a Response object.

Regarding unit testing - I'm not interested in the inner workings of the Service Reference since this is a 3rd party service.  I'm only interested in two things:

1. Does my code generate the correct Request object?
2. When the Service Reference returns it's response, do I process this response correctly?

Taking each in turn:

**Does my code generate the correct Request object?**

This I can do.  If anyone's interested in this, what I do is to replace my service reference with a RhinoMocks Mock object.  In my unit test I call the method on my Mock and then check the arguments passed in, comparing the actual Request object against the expected Request object.

**When the Service Reference returns it's response, do I process this response correctly?**

What I want to do here is to create a RhinoMocks Stub of my service reference, so that when it's called this stub returns a response object populated with my test data.

The problem that I face is that the response objects returned by this particular 3rd party service are extremely complex.  If I were to attempt to create one by hard-coding all the property values by hand then this would probably take me the best part of a whole day.

However, what I can very easily do is to capture the XML serialized response from this service.  I could then easily edit it's values and store this XML in one of my unit tests.

What I'm after is an easy way to then "deserialize" this "test" XML into a response object and use this to program the response from my Stub.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Griff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is quite simple:

```
public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
{
    using(Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        var s = new XmlSerializer(toType, "http://^your url^");
        return s.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Note that if you're using XML from a SOAP request, strip the SOAP envelop off first.

Griff